# Access Azure Databricks Delta Tables from Microsoft Dataverse(CDS)

Tags: azure, databricks, powerapps, common-data-service

Can Powerapps be connected to Delta Table that resides inside Azure Databricks?

Most of the articles hosted on Microsoft Docs suggest exporting data from Delta Tables to e.g. Azure Storage Account and then accessing it via powerapps.
Also I found none article that states that it is impossible.

I see that inside PowerApps portal, there is a way to import Parquet file, but I can't find the connection credentials that will work.